# Single variable nested lists from json file, convert to dataframe rows

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I have browsed stack overflow and the web, attempting many solutions that have been suggested to other problems and gotten to this stage, demonstrated below.

I apologise in advance for being very new to R and coding in general.

Situation:
I've acquired some data from a java source as a .json file. I wish to convert it into a data frame so i can more easily use it to run analysis on the change in value over time.

Problem:
The information appears in a multi layered nested list form in a json file.

It appears in the form:

```
{"daily":{"1534550400000":14005196,"1550016000000":5924765},"average":{"1534550400000":13750989,"1550016000000":7966277}}
```

There is the same amount of daily values as average values. "x" is a date code counting the time in milliseconds from jan 1 1970, and the value following ":" is an int.

When i use fromJSON to pull it into R, it comes out as nested lists:

```
Library(jsonlite)  
x<-fromJSON("short.json")
str(x)
List of 2
$ daily  :List of 2
..$ 1534550400000: int 14005196
..$ 1550016000000: int 5924765
$ average:List of 2
..$ 1534550400000: int 13750989
..$ 1550016000000: int 7966277
```

I separate the daily and average lists as they will be in different data frames.

```
daily<-x[[1]]
average<-x[[2]]
> str(daily)
List of 2
 $ 1534550400000: int 14005196
 $ 1550016000000: int 5924765
> str(average)
List of 2
 $ 1534550400000: int 13750989
 $ 1550016000000: int 7966277
```

If i continue with daily1<-daily[[1]] then i lose the time data which i need.

My thought process is that i should flatten the time lists and integers and create a data frame which i would separate the flattened information into two columns.

My primary issue with this is i am unsure how to flatten lists that are nested within another list.

In my reading of other peoples problems with lists, many have been using sapply or lapply, which appeared successful for them however I've reached dead ends.

Thanks in advance.

I have read the documentation for jsonlite, sapply, lapply and flatten provided by cran.

EDIT:
I have continued to look into this problem and have found a possible alternative method, whereby i use:

This table is showing all the values for daily and average and none of the timecodes.

```
as.data.frame(unlist(flatten(daily)))
1                  14005196
2                   5924765
3                  13750989
4                   7966277
```

Which appears closer to what i want, i will need to move every second value to a new column.

EDIT2: The desired out come would be for a table for daily:

```
      Time         Var
1 1534550400000 14005196
2 1550016000000 5924765
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to get the question. From my understanding, you want:

```
> as.data.frame(lapply(x, unlist))
                 daily  average
1534550400000 14005196 13750989
1550016000000  5924765  7966277
```

Comment: How would i go about editing the the date code 1534550400000, as it seams the data frame is using that as the row number? i want to multiply by 1.15741e-8 to get it in days and then add it to jan 1st 1970.

Comment: @Chris.S How do you get `1.15741e-8`?

Comment: The time code is measured in milliseconds since jan 1st 1970, so basic unit conversions from ms to days

Comment: @Chris.S `df <- as.data.frame(lapply(x, unlist))` then `rownames(df) <- as.Date(as.double(rownames(df))/(1000*60*60*24), origin = "1970-01-01")`